# Why am I not able to get proper dates in my graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am not able to get the dates in correct form in my output.It is concerned with plottng of 3 stock data (opening price) for 4 days on single axis.

My code is

```
# Import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history
avenue_df=get_history(symbol='DMART',start=date(2018,5,6),end=date(2018,5,10))

avenue_df.Open.plot(color='green', label='DMART')

shriram_df = get_history(symbol='SRTRANSFIN',start=date(2018,5,6),end=date(2018,5,10))
shriram_df.Open.plot(color='red', label='SHRI')

infy_df = get_history(symbol='INFY',start=date(2018,5,6),end=date(2018,5,10))
infy_df.Open.plot(color='blue', label='INFY')


# Add a legend in the top left corner of the plot
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

My output is

[image: my output is]

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: I want the dates mentioned in the code as my x axis in the output but,i am not able to understand that why am i getting 00,12,00,12 after each date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DayLocator and DateFormatter from [matplotlib.dates](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html?highlight=dates#module-matplotlib.dates)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history
avenue_df=get_history(symbol='DMART',start=date(2018,5,6),end=date(2018,5,10))

avenue_df.Open.plot(color='green', label='DMART')

shriram_df = get_history(symbol='SRTRANSFIN',start=date(2018,5,6),end=date(2018,5,10))
shriram_df.Open.plot(color='red', label='SHRI')

infy_df = get_history(symbol='INFY',start=date(2018,5,6),end=date(2018,5,10))
ax = infy_df.Open.plot(color='blue', label='INFY')


# Add a legend in the top left corner of the plot
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

# Display the plot

#Format the xaxis date
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d'))
plt.show()
```